# Upload via git-ftp was interrupted and stopped half way. Any idea on how to continue?

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

I was uploading to my remote server using git ftp init.

Due to battery drainage the system went off while the upload was half way. Now i have partial file in the remote server.

Is there any way I can continue the upload and harmonize the files between the local and remote server?

Do you know any git ftp command that can handle it automatically or continue from where the upload stopped?